# Get active menu when reaching div

Tags: jquery

I have this one page website with a fixed header and menu. Now I want to change the menu from home(where it starts) to contact, when it reaches the contact part of the website. Is there anyway to do this?

If someone could point me in the right direction,

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"...point me in the right direction"*

<kbd>**[DIRECTION DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eyojaz/1/edit)**</kbd>

on **$(window).scroll()** function - get your window scroll position using `scrollTop()` and store into a `var`.
Than check for your **element's** `.offset().top;` matches that `var` value + some extra amount of px (I used "100") - and grab that element `data-title`.

HTML:

```
 <div id="header">
   <h1></h1>
 </div>

  <div class="page" data-title="Home"> home page</div>
  <div class="page" data-title="About"> bout page</div>
  <div class="page" data-title="Info"> info page</div>
  <div class="page" data-title="Contact"> contact page</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{     
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background:#0ff;
  padding:15px;    
}
.page{     
  padding:20px;
  padding-top: 140px;
  background:#eee;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  min-height:800px;    
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand

    var $page = $('.page');

    function getTitle(){ 
        var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();       
        $page.each(function(){
            var pageOffs = $(this).offset().top,
                title = $(this).data('title');
            if( winScrollTop > pageOffs-100){               
                     $('h1').text( title );
            }
        });
    }
    getTitle();

    $(window).scroll( getTitle );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    divOffset = $('#contact').offset().top,
    dist = (divOffset - scrollTop);
    if (dist == 0) {
      $('.menuItem').text('contact');
    }
 });
```